# Matrix multiplication for certain matrix elements

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to update a list of regional supply with matrix multiplication.

I have a list of regional supply and a origin destination matrix which represents transition probability between each regions.
And I would like to get the In/Out list with matrix multiplication.

```
Supply = np.array([10, 20])
OD_matrix = np.array([0.3,0.7,0.5,0.5]).reshape(2,2)

          Destination
               0    1
          0 [[0.3, 0.7],
   Origin 1  [0.5, 0.5]]
```

In the above example there are two regions, region 1 and region 2 each with 10, 20 supply.
The matrix is a probability of transition between each region for example
OD_matrix[0][1] of the matrix is the transition of supply from region 0 to region1.

Now I can easily update the supply matrix with

```
Supply = np.dot(Supply,OD_matrix)
```

But how can I create a list of In/Out of each region like

```
Supply [10,20]
In  [10, 7]
Out [7 , 10]
Updated Supply [13,17]
```

If I were to create the "In" list, I know that I should multiply the matrix while excluding the element whose origin and destination is itself, and then add them.

How should I computate this matrix multiplication without using a for loop in larger matrixes?

Comment: Show the looping code

Answer (score 0):

By definition, to do matrix multiplication you do need for loops. There's just no way around it.

However, you can actually do matrix multiplication is less than `O(n^3)` time by using [Strassen's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm). You can look into it further in the link provided to see if that's truly more efficient and hence suitable for your case.

Comment: When using `numpy`, doing something without loops means using numpy methods without python level loops. There still are loops, but in compiled code.  It's a performance issue.